# how to implement a Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT for a fragment backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like my fragments backstack to have a single instance of every fragment added to it. In other words, when I recall a fragment already instantiated (and added to the backstack) without popping it from the backstack (i.e. with a `FragmentTransaction.replace` by passing its tag name) I would like it to have it ONLY on the top of the FragmentManager's backstack. I can use `FragmentTransaction.addToBackstack`, but this cannot delete previous fragment references and I don't want to pop the backstack to erase the previous reference, otherwise I lose part of the history I still would like to retain.